# Can R read grib file(when it is not raster) and convert it to ASCII file?

Tags: r, gdal, grib

I am trying to read this grib file  but I got an error.is there a way we can solve this problem

```
    grib <- readGDAL("C:\\file.grib") 

Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
  grib is a grib file, but no raster dataset was successfully identified.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not an R problem.

using gdal, I have this :

```
gdalinfo --debug on H14_2011010400.grib 

GRIB: Undefined parameter table (center 98-0 table 228).
GRIB: Undefined parameter table (center 98-0 table 228).
GRIB: Undefined parameter table (center 98-0 table 228).
GRIB: Undefined parameter table (center 98-0 table 228).
GRIB: Problems with ReadGrib1Record called by ReadGrib2Record
Inside ReadGrib1Record
GRIB1 GDS: Expect PV = 255 != 33

ERROR 4: H14_2011010400.grib is a grib file, but no raster dataset was successfully identified.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'H14_2011010400.grib'.
```

I think that your grib file is **wrongly encoded**, tryu to install wgrib to get more info.